# Difference of Two Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective*. In section 3.8.2 there is an example that says &E[i] - E equals i, assuming E is an array of 4-byte integers. Why isn't the answer 4i?

Comment: Tagging [tag:c] because I believe that's the language used in this book.  Please always use language tags.

Comment: When you subtract two pointers, the difference is the number of units of the size of the elements of the array.  It doesn't matter what the type of the elements of `E` are — they could be 1-byte, 2-byte, 4-byte, 8-byte integers, or structures, or unions, or floating-point types; the difference between `&E[i] - &E[0]` (aka `&E[i] - E`) is `i` — and the result type is `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how pointer arithmetic works in C.

Subtracting pointers gives a result in units of elements, not in units of bytes.  It's symmetric with the fact that if you want to access element 2 of the array `E`, you use `E[2]` or `*(E+2)`, not `E[8]` nor `*(E+8)`.